# Convert a String to Spinal Case

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

Challenge: Convert a string to spinal case. Spinal case is all-lowercase-words-joined-by-dashes

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  var res = str.replace(/\s/g, "-")
  var result = res.replace(/_/g, '').toLowerCase();
  return result;
}
```

Code works only if there are spaces between strings or if there are no underscores. I am stuck trying to pass the rest of the test-cases, does anybody else have any tips or ideas in mind?

```
spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap") should return "this-is-spinal-tap".
spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap") should return "this-is-spinal-tap".
spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show") should return "the-andy-griffith-show".
spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh") should return "teletubbies-say-eh-oh".
spinalCase("AllThe-small Things") should return "all-the-small-things".
```

Comment: How do you get the word boundaries?

Comment: You would probably need some api to break those into words for you. Question is not trivial. Is certainly far too broad as outlined in the [help]

Comment: How is Javascript supposed to know what part of the string is a word? This isn't possible without providing some array of words that can be indexed against.

Comment: Was your first example meant to be `exampleStringTwo`?  Otherwise what your asking for is not possible, even if you had the whole English dictionary to compare against, as you could have word overlaps..    eg. `website`, is that `web & site`, or `website`?..

Comment: Not all test cases use camelcase so apparently this is impossible. Let me rephrase this question then

Comment: Should `testsample` be `['test', 'sample']` or `['tests', 'ample`]`. Both seems correct. Even with a dictionary, it will be ambiguous unless unless there's no overlap possible.

Comment: To summarize: spaces, underscores, minus and Uppercase characters are word boundaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove all non-alphanumeric chars at the start/end of the string, replace these consecutive chars with `-` anywhere else, then you may insert a hyphen in between lower- and uppercase letters, and then turn all to lower case.

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$|([\W_]+)/g, function ($0, $1) {
              return $1 ? "-" : "";
         }).replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase();
}

console.log(spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap")); // "this-is-spinal-tap".
console.log(spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap")); // "this-is-spinal-tap".
console.log(spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show")); // "the-andy-griffith-show".
console.log(spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh")); //"teletubbies-say-eh-oh".
console.log(spinalCase("AllThe-small Things")); // "all-the-small-things".
```

**Details**

- `.replace(/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$|([\W_]+)/g, function ($0, $1) { return $1 ? "-" : ""; })` - removes all non-alphanumeric chars at the start (`^[\W_]+`)/end (`[\W_]+$`) of the string, replace these consecutive chars with `-` anywhere else (`([\W_]+)`)
- `.replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-')` - insert a hyphen in between lower- and uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this [question version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55464314/2): When input string use [camel-case](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) then we not need dictionary and can use regexp only:

```js
let s="exampleStringTwoThe-smallThing";

let r=s.replace(/([A-Z][a-z\-]*)/g, ' $1');

console.log(r);
```

For current question version:

```
s.replace(/( |_)+/g,'-').replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase()
```

```js
function spinalCase(s) {
  return s.replace(/( |_)+/g,'-').replace(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase();
}

console.log( spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap") ) // should return "this-is-spinal-tap".
console.log( spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap") ) // should return "this-is-spinal-tap".
console.log( spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show") ) // should return "the-andy-griffith-show".
console.log( spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh") ) // should return "teletubbies-say-eh-oh".
console.log( spinalCase("AllThe-small Things") ) // should return "all-the-small-things".
```

I improve solution by remove on `replace` using Wiktor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464743/860099)

Comment: Just add spaces and _ to the regex, then it should also work with the current version (good task for the OP though)